# How to sort on key resulted by groupByKey in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Need help in sorting on key after groupByKey output :

```
val skuRDD2:RDD[(String,Iterable[(String,imageinfo2))]= DF.select("ID", "TAG","MEDIA_ID","IMAGE_NAME","PATH").rdd
            .map(r => (r .getString(0),( r.getString(1),ImageInfo2(r.getString(2),r.getString(3),r.getString(4)))) )
      .groupByKey()
```

I want to sort on TAG ie. key in Iterable[(String,imageinfo2)) in above groupByKey output.

Input (above groupByKey output)-

```
(skuid,Map(largeImage_4 -> [Media/Device Images/Large Images/Huawei Images Large/GR5GRY-4,m110005,GR5GRY-4], largeImage_1 -> [Media/Device Images/Large Images/Huawei Images Large/GR5GRY-1,m110002,GR5GRY-1])
```

Expected output -

```
(skuid,Map(largeImage_1 -> [Media/Device Images/Large Images/Huawei Images Large/GR5GRY-1,m110002,GR5GRY-1], largeImage_4 -> [Media/Device Images/Large Images/Huawei Images Large/GR5GRY-4,m110005,GR5GRY-4])
```

Can someone help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyzing your provided data made me conclude that *all you are missing is simple `mapValues` function* where you do the *sorting*.

```
.mapValues(x => x.toList.sortBy(y => y._1))
```

So your code should be

```
val skuRDD2:RDD[(String,Iterable[(String,ImageInfo2)])] = DF.select("ID", "TAG","MEDIA_ID","IMAGE_NAME","PATH").rdd
  .map(r => (r .getString(0),( r.getString(1),ImageInfo2(r.getString(2),r.getString(3),r.getString(4)))) )
  .groupByKey().mapValues(x => x.toList.sortBy(y => y._1))
```

I hope the answer is helpful